# Nonstandard io redirection

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

How would you go about redirecting a script's stdout and stderr to a file, while also sending the script's stderr to stdout.

To illustrate:

testscript:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "this goes to stdout"
echo "this goes to stderr" >&2
```

Execute testscript in such a way that it prints this to the console:

```
this goes to stderr
```

and this goes to the logfile:

```
this goes to stdout
this goes to stderr
```

I feel like I got close using a `fifo`, but never got there.  What's needed is a `tee` for stderr.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it isn't really fair for the people working on answers right now, but I think I got it:

```
if [ ! -e /tmp/deployed.err ]
then
  mkfifo /tmp/deployed.err
fi

tee -a testlog </tmp/deployed.err &

./testscript 2>/tmp/deployed.err 1>>testlog
```

It appears to work, but I'm worried that the messages in the log will get out of order.  Anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
command 2>&1 | tee somefile
```

will send BOTH stderr and stdout to `tee` so, both going to file and stdout too.

if you want redirect the `stderr` and stdout to different `tee`, you can use something like:

```
command > >(tee out.log) 2> >(tee err.log >&2)
```

and so on... (the spaces between `> >(` are mandatory)

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

```
./script 2>&1 1>log | tee -a log
```

the stdout is send to log in `1>log` and tee does the job of sending it to stdout and log.

PS: Somehow I have a bad feeling about this method. Please comment if you feel so.

Answer (score 0):

simething simplier. this is based on bashizm internal fork
at first, test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..1000}; do
    echo STDOUT $i>&1
    echo STDERR $i>&2
done
```

and next, redirecting script:

```
(./xxtext.sh 1>>logfile)2>&1|\ #subprocess/fork in brackets with redir stdout to logfile.
#above, main process redirect stderr to stdout for properly pipe
while read x; do echo $x; echo $x>>logfile; done #second read sequently stdin
#redirected from stderr, and both print to the screen and append to logfile.
```

Unfortunately this not save properly sequence, because two streams are managed by two different process with pipe buffering with them.

If you really want save sequence, only way is using 'select' system call and read both stdout and stderr from internally opened script. I belive bash doesn't support this.
You can do this in C or Perl or other more advanced lang.
Usefull example in perl i found at: http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=419919
this calls 'bc' command.